# Calling methods in jsf

Tags: jsf

I wanted to make the possibility of booking /remove  booking the product page.
Reservations is ok, removing unfortunately not ...

```
@ManagedBean(name = "wardrobeDetailsBean")
@SessionScoped
//@RequestScoped
public class WardrobeDetailsBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    WardrobeService wardrobeService;
    @Inject
    AuthBean authBean;

    // other fields + setters, getters

    @ManagedProperty("#{param.id}")
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsernameReserving() {
        this.selectedWardrobe = wardrobeService.getWardrobeById(id);
        String usernameById = selectedWardrobe.getReservingUserId().getUsername();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(usernameById.substring(0, 2));
        sb.append("...");
        sb.append(usernameById.substring(usernameById.length() - 2, usernameById.length()));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            dbImage1 = new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else if (id != null) {
            this.selectedWardrobe = wardrobeService.getWardrobeById(id);
            }
        }
    }

    public String reserve() {
        this.selectedWardrobe = wardrobeService.getWardrobeById(id);
        if (authBean.getUser() != null && authBean.getUser().getId() != null) {
            selectedWardrobe.setReservingUserId(authBean.getUser());
            wardrobeService.reserveProduct(selectedWardrobe);
            return null;
        } else {
            return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }

    public void unreserve() {
        this.selectedWardrobe = wardrobeService.getWardrobeById(id);
        selectedWardrobe.setReservingUserId(null);
        wardrobeService.reserveProduct(selectedWardrobe);
    }
}
```

*productView.xhtml*

```
<h:commandButton id="reserve" styleClass="btn-u btn-u-sea-shop btn-u-lg" rendered="#{wardrobeDetailsBean.selectedWardrobe.reservingUserId eq null}"
    value="Reserve" action="#{wardrobeDetailsBean.reserve()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="reservePanel"/>
</h:commandButton>

<h:outputText value="This product has been reserved by #{wardrobeDetailsBean.usernameReserving}" rendered="#{wardrobeDetailsBean.selectedWardrobe.reservingUserId ne null}"/>
<br />
 <input type="hidden" name="remoteUser" value="#{request.remoteUser}"/> 
// added using guidance from the answers
<h:commandButton id="unreserve" styleClass="btn-u btn-u-red btn-u-lg" rendered="#{request.remoteUser eq wardrobeDetailsBean.selectedWardrobe.reservingUserId.username}"
    value="Unreserve" action="#{wardrobeDetailsBean.unreserve()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="reservePanel"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

When I removed the `rendered="#{request.remoteUser eq wardrobeDetailsBean.selectedWardrobe.reservingUserId.username}"`, it works.

When the reservation is clicked it should only be visible button for removal.
What is wrong, it does not work? The log any errors I have not.

After using guidance from the answers, application works like this.
[image]

I click "Reserve". The product has been reserved, the button will be swapped.

[image]

I click "Unreserve" and still the method is not called, I lose the information about the product (refresh the page returns information about the product, but the product is still reserved)

[image]

Comment: Is it JSF 2 or JSF 1?

Comment: Mojtaba. It is JSF 2.

Comment: what if you make it return String instead of void method?

Comment: Please describe what is happening? does the unreserve method is called? or just you have problem with rendering?

Comment: The same does not work

Comment: Starts init method but not anymore.

Comment: I have breakpoint in the first line of the method unreserve and I see that they do not enter there.

Comment: There should be a point where `getUsername()` method od the reserving user id gets called in order to evaluate its equality to the remote user. You could check it out.

Comment: use browser developer tools and see what is printed in hidden input element

Comment: value is the name of the logged user

Comment: is it correct to use  'reserveProduct(selectedWardrobe)' of  'wardrobeService' in 'unreserve' method?

Comment: ie? I set null, so that the product is no longer assigned to the user. This does not change the fact that it still does not come to this method ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendered attribute of button is evaluated in the process of submitting form before request is reached to your bean method,

and as you checked `request.remoteUser` in rendered method, it will be empty for new request (post request of action), the rendered evaluation will be "false", so your method is not called.

So you must make sure that rendered attribute of your button and its parents remain to true during form submission.

That's the cause when you remove rendered attribute, it works fine.

As a workaround you can add a hidden input to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="remoteUser" value="#{request.remoteUser}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="#{param.id}"/>
```

**Update: another solution**

another solution is to use one single button, but use a conditional value attribute and a toggle method:

```
<h:commandButton id="toggle" 
    styleClass="btn-u btn-u-#{(wardrobeDetailsBean.selectedWardrobe.reservingUserId eq null) ? 'sea-shop' : 'red' } btn-u-lg" 
    value="#{(wardrobeDetailsBean.selectedWardrobe.reservingUserId eq null) ? 'Reserve' : 'Unreserve'}" 
    action="#{wardrobeDetailsBean.toggle()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="reservePanel"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

And in your bean,  use a toggle method:

```
public String toggle() {
        this.selectedWardrobe = wardrobeService.getWardrobeById(id);
        if(selectedWardrobe.getReservingUserId() == null){
            if (authBean.getUser() != null && authBean.getUser().getId() != null) {
                selectedWardrobe.setReservingUserId(authBean.getUser());
                wardrobeService.reserveProduct(selectedWardrobe);
                return null;
            } else {
                return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
            }
        }else{
            this.selectedWardrobe = wardrobeService.getWardrobeById(id);
            selectedWardrobe.setReservingUserId(null);
            wardrobeService.reserveProduct(selectedWardrobe);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is beyond the task of this line there anything else I should change?

Comment: editted that line, so place the new code in your form.

Comment: Updated previous solution and added another solution, please first edit previous solution and if doesn't work, if you want check the other solution. I am still sure that the problem is your rendered is evaluated as false when posting unreserve request

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot Mojtaba!

Comment: your welcome @user3128303